# Issue to save excel file with Python/Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, save

I have trouble saving a file/moving it in Python when my script is launched from Jenkins.

I have a small function which is designed to move an output file from the working directory to another directory. When my script is launched locally everything goes fine. When I try to have it run by Jenkins I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...\shutil.py", line 522, in move
os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:   

'MyNicelyOutputtedFile' -> 'C:\\TheDestinationFolder'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:   'C:\\TheDestinationFolder'
```

I know that some people have been through the same issue but I don't see how they solved it. I also have an issue when I try to save directly my file in the destination folder using Pandas. Any hint? Many thanks.

Comment: The machine where the „_script is launched locally_“ and the machine Jenkins is running on are the same?

Comment: @ Gerold Broser: yes. Everything is run on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

After quite some time spent on the issue a colleague provided me with a great hint: reset drive mapping at the beginning of the job. It works fine when doing so.